# Cosa significa "dilagare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Il cielo di pietra*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Correvo trasportato dalla colata di lava tra orti appartati e templi di marmo. Udii il canto e un arpeggio; due voci s'alternavano; riconobbi quella di Rdix - ma quanto cambiata! - che teneva dietro alla voce ignota. Una scritta sull'archivolto, in caratteri greci: Orpheos. Sfondai l'uscio, *dilagai* oltre la soglia. La vidi, solo un istante, accanto all'arpa.

Ho letto la [definizione del verbo "dilagare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dilagare/). Comunque non riesco a capire il suo significato in questo contesto. Ha forse qualcosa a che vedere col fatto che il narratore è trasportato dalla lava di un vulcano?

Comment: Non ho letto nessuno dei libri, ma intuitivamente (e basandomi sulla tua affermazione) ho dedotto che effettivamente il protagonista sia "trasportato" dalla lava. Cercando un po su Google per avere velocemente qualche informazione in più capisco che anche il tono di tutta la serie di romanzi è piuttosto immaginario e fantasioso, e questo non escluderebbe che il narratore possa essere fisicamente trasportato dalla lava. Sai se ci sono altri brani nel testo che confermano quest'ipotesi? O quel "correvo trasportato" è da interpretarsi solo sulla base di se stesso?

Comment: @kos: Sì, è così. In questo racconto, Qfwfq abita nell'interno del globo terrestre insieme a Rdix, che a un certo punto scappa fuori. Un giorno, Qfwfq profitta dell'eruzione di un vulcano per essere trasportato dalla lava e uscire alla ricerca di Rdix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ha forse qualcosa a che vedere col fatto che il narratore è trasportato dalla lava di un vulcano?

Direi di sì.

Si capisce dal testo che il protagonista è in balia della lava, altrimenti non ne verrebbe trasportato; quindi si può anche dire che il protagonista è un tutt'uno con la lava.

Per costruzione se la lava dilaga dentro la casa anche il protagonista dilaga dentro la casa; quindi direi che in questo caso il protagonista che "dilaga" oltre la soglia è una "mezza" (mezza perché tecnicamente non è falso che il protagonista "dilaga" con la lava che lo trasporta, ma è anche vero che una persona non "dilaga", e quindi qui secondo me il gioco di parole è intenzionale) metafora per descrivere la veemenza e l'invasività con cui il protagonista la attraversa, che sono pari a quelle della lava che lo sta trasportando.

Comment: Il narratore è un personaggio chiamato Qfwfq, il protagonista di tutte le *cosmicomiche*.

Comment: Scusate il brutto errore, ma non ho letto nessuno dei libri. Corretto

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il vocabolario Treccani:

> Riferito ad acque, diffondersi rapidamente e largamente sul terreno, in modo da formare come un lago

ma anche

> Diffondersi largamente e rapidamente, detto soprattutto di costumi e comportamenti sociali negativi

Nel brano Calvino dice che il protagonista ha sfondato la porta e l'ha attraversata in modo molto rapido (questa la "traduzione" letterale). Immagina di avere la camera piena d'acqua e ad un tratto la porta viene sfondata. L'acqua della camera irrompe dall'altro lato. Questa è un po' l'immagine che Calvino vuole descrivere: l'atto di attraversare la porta come un fiume o un lago in piena.

Answer (score 1):

Direi che è l'unico significato plausibile.

Purtroppo Calvino tende ad avere un uso molto *personale* dell'italiano: non credo che, in nessun altro contesto, si possa usare *dilagare dall'uscio*

Comment: Vuoi dire che il narratore "dilaga oltre la soglia dell'uscio" perché viene trasportato dalla lava del vulcano?

Comment: “Purtroppo”?  :-)

Comment: No! Non è trasportato dalla lava. Scappa così velocemente dalla lava che sembra irrompere come un fiume in piena dall'altra parte della porta.

Comment: @DaG purtroppo per chi vuole imparare l'italiano. Io oserei dire che Calvino non scrive in italiano ma in una sua lingua che risulta comprensibile ma estranea a chi parla italiano. Un po' come un bambino che per esclamare lo stupore per un fulmine dice: "Un lampone!" E' comprensibile, ma di certo non è uso corretto della lingua. D'altronde questa cosa crea emozione nel lettore... ma questa è la poetica.